# Copy data from closed workbook based on variable user defined path

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, xlm

I have exhausted my search capabilities looking for a solution to this.  Here is an outline of what I would like to do:

- User opens macro-enabled Excel file
- Immediate prompt displays for user to enter or select file path of desired workbooks.  They will need to select two files, and the file names may not be consistent
- After entering the file locations, the first worksheet from the first file selection will be copied to the first worksheet of the macro-enabled workbook, and the first worksheet of the second file selection will be copied to the second worksheet of the macro-enabled workbook.

I've come across some references to ADO, but I am really not familiar with that yet.

Edit:  I have found a code to import data from a closed file.  I will need to tweak the range to return the variable results.

```
    Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

    path = "C:\Users\crathbun\Desktop"
    file = "test.xlsx"
    sheet = "Sheet1"
    ref = "A1:R30"

     '   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String

     '   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If

     '   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
    Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)

     '   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

Sub TestGetValue()

    path = "C:\Users\crathbun\Desktop"
    file = "test"
    sheet = "Sheet1"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To 30
        For C = 1 To 18
            a = Cells(r, C).Address
            Cells(r, C) = GetValue(path, file, sheet, a)
        Next C
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now, I need a command button or userform that will immediately prompt the user to define a file path, and import the data from that file.

Comment: have you already built some code yet? where are you stuck?

Comment: @JMax - I added the code that I currently have available.  It is not much and I'm not even sure I am going in the right direction.

Comment: @user955289: Any reason why you wouldn't want to open the two files? The code is straight and simple to import the sheets from those file using workbooks.open()

Comment: I don't mind if the files are opened during process.  I just didn't want the user to have to open the files individually.  I just need them to be able to select or navigate to the desired files.

Comment: @user955289: Posting code in few minutes...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> > > I don't mind if the files are opened during process. I just didn't want the user to have to open the files individually. I just need them to be able to select or navigate to the desired files

Here is a basic code. This code asks user to select two files and then imports the relevant sheet into the current workbook. I have given two options. Take your pick :)

**TRIED AND TESTED**

**OPTION 1 (Import the Sheets directly instead of copying into sheet1 and 2)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Ret1, Ret2

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    '~~> Get the first File
    Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select first file")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

    '~~> Get the 2nd File
    Ret2 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select Second file")
    If Ret2 = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)
    wb2.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=wb1.Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Blah Blah 1"
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret2)
    wb2.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Blah Blah 2"
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Set wb1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

**OPTION 2 (Import the Sheets contents into sheet1 and 2)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Ret1, Ret2

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    '~~> Get the first File
    Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select first file")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

    '~~> Get the 2nd File
    Ret2 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select Second file")
    If Ret2 = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)
    wb2.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wb1.Sheets(1).Cells
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret2)
    wb2.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wb1.Sheets(2).Cells
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Set wb1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow!  This is perfect.  I have tried both options and will most likely use the second option.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: I've logged in just to thank and make you a compliment, Siddharth Rout. This code of yours is a real work of art. I've been looking for a code like this for a long time. So glad I found it. From now on, my spreadsheets will have a totally different approach. Thanks for sharing such an amazing piece of knowledge. :)

Answer (score 2):

The function below reads data from a closed Excel file and returns the result in an array. It loses formatting, formulas etc. You might want to call the isArrayEmpty function (at the bottom) in your main code to test that the function returned something.

```
Public Function getDataFromClosedExcelFile(parExcelFileName As String, parSheetName As String) As Variant
'see http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=19559
'returns an array (1 to nRows, 1 to nCols) which should be tested with isArrayEmpty in the calling function

  Dim locConnection As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim locRst As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim locConnectionString As String
  Dim locQuery As String
  Dim locCols As Variant
  Dim locResult As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long

  On Error GoTo error_handler

  locConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
  & "Data Source=" & parExcelFileName & ";" _
  & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"

  locQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & parSheetName & "$]"

  locConnection.Open ConnectionString:=locConnectionString
  locRst.Open Source:=locQuery, ActiveConnection:=locConnection
  If locRst.EOF Then 'Empty sheet or only one row
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''''         FIX: an empty sheet returns "F1"
    ''''''         http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318373
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If locRst.Fields.Count = 1 And locRst.Fields(0).Name = "F1" Then Exit Function 'Empty sheet
    ReDim locResult(1 To 1, 1 To locRst.Fields.Count) As Variant
    For i = 1 To locRst.Fields.Count
      locResult(1, i) = locRst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i
  Else
    locCols = locRst.GetRows
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''''         FIX: an empty sheet returns "F1"
    ''''''         http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318373
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If locRst.Fields.Count = 1 And locRst.Fields(0).Name = "F1" And UBound(locCols, 2) = 0 And locCols(0, 0) = "" Then Exit Function 'Empty sheet

    ReDim locResult(1 To UBound(locCols, 2) + 2, 1 To UBound(locCols, 1) + 1) As Variant

    If locRst.Fields.Count <> UBound(locCols, 1) + 1 Then Exit Function 'Not supposed to happen

    For j = 1 To UBound(locResult, 2)
      locResult(1, j) = locRst.Fields(j - 1).Name
    Next j
    For i = 2 To UBound(locResult, 1)
      For j = 1 To UBound(locResult, 2)
        locResult(i, j) = locCols(j - 1, i - 2)
      Next j
    Next i
  End If

  locRst.Close
  locConnection.Close
  Set locRst = Nothing
  Set locConnection = Nothing

  getDataFromClosedExcelFile = locResult

  Exit Function
error_handler:
  'Wrong file name, sheet name, or other errors...
  'Errors (#N/A, etc) on the sheet should be replaced by Null but should not raise an error
  If locRst.State = ADODB.adStateOpen Then locRst.Close
  If locConnection.State = ADODB.adStateOpen Then locConnection.Close
  Set locRst = Nothing
  Set locConnection = Nothing

End Function

Public Function isArrayEmpty(parArray As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns false if not an array or dynamic array that has not been initialised (ReDim) or has been erased (Erase)

  If IsArray(parArray) = False Then isArrayEmpty = True
  On Error Resume Next
  If UBound(parArray) < LBound(parArray) Then isArrayEmpty = True: Exit Function Else: isArrayEmpty = False

End Function
```

Sample use:

```
Sub test()

  Dim data As Variant

  data = getDataFromClosedExcelFile("myFile.xls", "Sheet1")
  If Not isArrayEmpty(data) Then
    'Copies content on active sheet
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Resize(UBound(data,1), UBound(data,2)) = data
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the function.  I would like to stay away from ADO for the moment until I am able to study it some more.  I am going to keep this as a reference when I am more comfortable with ADO.

Comment: you could also dump the recordset into the sheet using the `CopyFromRecordset` method on the range object.